# Observable for selector - RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactivex, rx-cocoa

I'm trying to migrate my FRP understanding from **ReactiveCocoa 2.5** to **RxSwift** and I have one misunderstanding. In ReactiveCocoa, I used `rac_signalForSelector` when I wanted to observe an invocation of a method. Is there any way to implement this logic using RxSwift?

I wrote a small example in which I want to dispose a subscription when the `test` method invokes. But in the subscribe block I can still see a `next(6)` event. What am I doing wrong?

```
let subject = PublishSubject<Int>()
subject.takeUntil(self.rx.sentMessage(#selector(test))).subscribe { event in
    print(event)
}

subject.onNext(3)
test()
subject.onNext(6)

//////////////////

func test() {

}
```

Comment: It's probably because `self` is non-`NSObject`.  I wouldn't recommend using `sentMessage` if you can help it.  Like you've seen, it can behave strangely and at best, it's a code smell.  Use it only when necessary.

Comment: @solidcell thanks for settings my understanding a bit more!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`sentMessage`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/b68fc4260e4c9934a6fbb6c36940c6e2e8f3b375/RxCocoa/Common/Observables/NSObject%2BRx.swift#L128):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.rx.sentMessage(#selector(UIViewController.viewWillAppear(_:)))
            .subscribe({ e in
                print(e)
            })
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> next([0])

Or another example:

```
class SomeNSObjectClass: NSObject {
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myObj = SomeNSObjectClass()
        myObjc.rx.sentMessage(NSSelectorFromString("dealloc"))
            .subscribe({ e in
                print(e)
            })
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> next([])
>   completed

Comment: Thanks for your answering! But can you explain what am I doing wrong with added example above. I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 4):

you should use `dynamic` modifier for `test` function that access to `test` function is never inlined or devirtualized by the compiler.

like this:
`dynamic func test() {}`

Answer (score 2):

I am adding this comment after encounter the same problem but now I've solved it.

The solution for me, -- I am sorry if this is not the thing you search for but hope will help others with the same issue --, was just adding `dynamic` modifier for the observed function.

This is the code

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    rx.sentMessage(#selector(ViewController.test))
        .debug("Test", trimOutput: true)
        .subcribe()
        .disposed(by: bag)
}

@objc dynamic test() {}
```

Without `dynamic` modifier the call to test isn't observed because the debug doesn't print anything.

I am new to RxSwift.

Thanks @zhongwuzw above, I got the idea after read his comment.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which avoids using sentMessage, is to define a testSubject and trigger a next event on it in your test function.

```
let subject = PublishSubject<Int>()
let testSubject = PublishSubject<Void>()

subject.takeUntil(testSubject).subscribe { event in
    print(event)
}

subject.onNext(3)
test()
subject.onNext(6)

//////////////////

func test() {
    testSubject.onNext(())
}
```

This will only print until test() is called.

Answer (score 0):

RxSwift has Already added this method.
look at this [issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/181#issuecomment-168076551)